# Question about permissions in Ubuntu

Tags: permissions

I am currently trying to download Linaro Lava onto my VirtualMachine. When I do this command I am getting a permission denied error:

```
echo 'deb http://people.linaro.org/~neil.williams/ubuntu/ trusty main' > /etc/apt/sources.d/lava.list
```

Some quick help on this would be appreciated

Comment: put "sudo " in front of it please.

Comment: Have you tried adding sudo first? or to log in as root?

Answer (score 2):

Your command should be,

```
sudo sh -c "echo 'deb http://people.linaro.org/~neil.williams/ubuntu/ trusty main' > /etc/apt/sources.d/lava.list"
```

Try to run the command in a subshell or otherwise you will get an permission denied error.

Answer (score 0):

I guess, there are 2 things:

1. I guess you're trying to run the command as the normal user, but only the `root` user can create a file there. So you should run the command with a `sudo su` beforehand to gain root privileges.
2. You're putting it in `/etc/apt/sources.d/lava.list`, but it should be `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/lava.list` as apt usually checks the `sources.list.d` directory. But I'm not 100% sure whether that changed for Linaro Lava.

So, check

```
ls /etc/apt/
```

and if there's the directory `sources.list.d` then run:

```
sudo su
deb http://people.linaro.org/~neil.williams/ubuntu/ trusty main' > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/lava.list
```

but if there's the `sources.d` directory, then run:

```
sudo su
deb http://people.linaro.org/~neil.williams/ubuntu/ trusty main' > /etc/apt/sources.d/lava.list
```